# Css dropdown menu pushes content down -fix for newbies?

Tags: html, css, menu, blogger, html-select

I have looked though this site and found various answers, but none worked for me or I didn't know what to do exactly. Whenever I hover over the menu, the main content get pushed down & when I add "position:absolute" (I've tried some places^^), the whole menu gets deactivated or disappears enirely.

I have a blogger site and use a template from here: http://www.5202.de/2012/10/avantgardistisches-simple-wei-layout.html   --> Download.

Please consider, when posting an answer, that I'm a total newbie in coding,and need very precise info;) I've made the menu with a generator, but I'm quite happy with it apart from that problem. 
I really hope you can help and I think other newbies would benefit from an easy to understand/implement answer, too:)

---

### Heres the css:

```
 .PageList {text-align:center !important;}
 .PageList li {display:inline !important; float:none !important;}
 ul#main-nav {font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;margin:0;padding:0;float:left;width:100%;font-size:0.9em;}
 ul#main-nav li {margin:0;padding:0;list-  style:none;float:left;margin:0;width:9em;position:relative;}
 ul#main-nav li a {text- decoration:none;display:block;padding:0.6em;color:#0e0e0e;background:#cfcfcf;border-   left:2px solid #fff;border-right:2px solid #fff;}
 ul#main-nav li a:hover, ul#main-nav    li a:focus {background:#ece1cf;border-  left:2px solid gray;border-right:2px solid gray;}
 ul#main-nav li ul {padding:0;margin:0;display:none;}
 ul#main-nav li:hover ul {display:block;}
 ul#main-nav li ul li {float:none;}
 ul#main-nav li ul li a {font-size:0.9em;}]]>
```

Not sure about the Page list belonging, but anyways.

---

### Now here's the html

```
<ul id="main-nav">
<li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com">About </a>
  <ul>
 <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.de/p/about-me.html">Me</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com/p/about-this-blog.html">This blog</a>      </li>
  <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com/p/ressources.html">Ressources</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com/p/legal-stuff.html">Legel stuff</a>   </li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com">Photography</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.de/p/photography.html">Projects</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.de/p/ausrustung.html">Equipment </a></li>
   <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com/2012/09/13-fotografie-  fragen.html">Questions</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
   <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com">Scrappy Art</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com/p/scrap-and-art.html">Scrapbooking</a>    </li>
   <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com/p/art-journals.html">Art Journals </a>  </li>
   <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com/p/mixed-media.html">Mixed-Media</a>  </li>
   <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com/search/label/crop">Crops & Co.</a> </li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com/p/diy.html">DIY </a></li>
   <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com">Freebies</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.de/p/free.html">Free Stuff</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.de/p/free.html">Free Tutorials</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com/p/legal-stuff.html">Terms of Use</a>   </li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com">Favorites</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com/p/and-you.html">Blogging Friends</a>  </li>
    <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com/p/all-my-faves.html">More Faves</a>   </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
     <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com">Features</a>
     <ul>
     <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com/search/label/alice">Wonderland</a>   </li>
     <li><a   href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com/search/label/smashbook">Smashbook</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com/search/label/foto-tipps">Photo- Tips</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com/search/label/book">Books</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com/search/label/lost">Lost Places</a> </li>
     </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com">Travel </a>
     <ul>
     <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com/search/label/la-gomera">La  Gomera</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com/search/label/london">London</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com/search/label/wroclaw">Wroclaw</a></li>
     </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="http://imagicallery.blogspot.com/p/bloghintergrunde.html">Contact</a>   </li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: Can you post jsfiddle ?

Comment: Sorry, I've never done anything jsfiddle, but if necessary I could try.  I don't use a javascript for the menue, but it's possible that there's another java somewhere active. My page is back online, now, too.

Answer (score 1):

How about you call the menu from another file (header) and set the background transparent make sure the body section overlaps the header when the drop down happens.

Answer (score 0):

find  `ul#main-nav li ul {padding:0;margin:0;display:none;}`

and change like this

```
 ul#main-nav li ul {
                   padding:0;margin:0;
                   display:none;
                  position:absolute:/*Added*/
                  z-index:2;/*Added*/
}
```

You can change position of your child ul by giving position like `top:10px;left:10px;` etc

Working **[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/b5ybV/1/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting and even writing a demo!! However, I tried this version (changed the : to ; too^^) and now the content doesn't drop anymore, but the menu bars that should drop down, don't either. I've put my site online again, if that helps, you can see it here: http://imagicallery.blogspot.com

Comment: Now I changed the postition back to "relative" so the visitors can at least use the menu, but then the content dropping is back of course... I guess it's probably something in my template that stops your solution from working???